# Trying to add a section every 2 indexPath.row swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Having a little problem with tableviews. I want to add a section to the tableview without messing with the content of the other data in the table. I want to add (cell3, thiscell) after every 2 indexpath.row 
What i have is a section on the storyboard which is one cell that i want to add after every 2 index path without messing with all the other information. How would i use the insert section function? or is there any other way to do it?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    if indexPath.section == 0 && cell1 == true{
        let cellIdentifier = “cell1"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = “cell1"
        cell.subNameLabel.text = ""
        return cell
    } else  if indexPath.section == 2 && vally == true{
        let cellIdentifier = "cell2"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = “Smiles"
        cell.subNameLabel.text = ""
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let cellIdentifier = “cell3"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! thisCell
        print("add this after indexpath 2")
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cellIdentifier = "SubCategoryTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
        cell.loading.hidden = false
        cell.loading.startAnimating()
        cell.nameLabel.text = subCat[indexPath.row].subCategoryName
        cell.subNameLabel.text = subCat[indexPath.row].subCategoryDesc
        return cell
    }
    let cell2: SubCategoryTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubCategoryTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
    cell2.userInteractionEnabled = false
    return cell2
}
```

Comment: One trick for hiding cells is to implement the `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method on `UITableViewDelegate` and return zero if you want to hide the cell - simpler than an insertion if you always know what's going to be in the cell

Comment: @RichTolley The problem I’m having is when i populate the table where i have  indexPath.row == 2 it puts the new cell in but then when i reaches the else if section == 1 it skips out the index path.row 2

Comment: You logic looks a bit odd there- you have tests on `indexPath.section` in 3 branches of the `if..else` statement, and `indexPath.row` in the one you mention. Not clear what the intention is either from your code or your question. What does 'every 2 indexpath.row mean' - do you mean that every 3rd row should be a special cell, or that the 3rd row in each section should be the special row. A 'section' in a table view means a group of cells - but you then say it's one cell. I'd try rewriting the question (and possibly the code a bit) - you may find the solution becomes clearer when you do.

Comment: @RichTolley i am going over the code now. Yeh i want after every 2 index path.row meaning that every 3rd row should be a special cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexPath.row value is intended to match indexes your underlying array of supporting data.  Presenting additional "virtual" cells in place of rows does not add them, it merely shows a different cell at the corresponding row.

You have two choices:

1) take into account the progressive offset that your "in-between" cells create in the subCat[row] and the IndexPath.row.

2) use actual sections and segment and mat pairs of entries to indexPath.row 0 and 1 in each section.

For #1, you could create a pair of mapping functions and use them to convert indexPath.row to and from indexes in subCat[]

```
func indexFromRow(row:int) -> int?
{ return row % 3 == 2 ? nil : row - row/3 }

func rowFromIndex(index:Int) -> Int
{ return index + index/2 }
```

Then, when returning you cell, you can use the functions to establish the correspondance between rows and indexes:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
  if let subCatIndex = indexFromRow(indexPath.row)
  {
     // build a SubCategoryTableViewCell cell, feed it with subCat[subCatIndex] data and return it
  }
  else
  {
     // build a thisCell cell and return it 
  }
}
```

you will also need to adjust the number of rows returned for the section to make room for the intermediate cells

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
 { return rowForIndex(subCat.count-1) + 1 }
```

Everywhere in you code where you receive an IndexPath and need to know the index in subCat[], you'll need to use the rowToIndex() function

When you want to know the index path of an item in subCat[] at a given index, you'll have to us indexToRow() to build the indexPath

For #2, you will have to use a similar technique to map indexPath.row and indexes in subCat[], but you'll also have to deal with sections and I don't think you can use a reusable cell for section headers.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

You want to display for *cell3* for indexPath.row = 2 in all sections or any specific section?

In case if you want to display in all sections:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
// Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.

if(indexPath.row == 2){
 let cellIdentifier = "cell3"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! thisCell
    print("add this after indexpath 2")
    return cell
}
else if indexPath.section == 0 && cell1 == true{
    let cellIdentifier = "cell1"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = “cell1"
    cell.subNameLabel.text = ""
    return cell
} else  if indexPath.section == 2 && vally == true{
    let cellIdentifier = "cell2"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = “Smiles"
    cell.subNameLabel.text = ""
    return cell
} else if indexPath.section == 1 {
    let cellIdentifier = "SubCategoryTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
    cell.loading.hidden = false
    cell.loading.startAnimating()
    cell.nameLabel.text = subCat[indexPath.row].subCategoryName
    cell.subNameLabel.text = subCat[indexPath.row].subCategoryDesc
    return cell
}
let cell2: SubCategoryTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubCategoryTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
cell2.userInteractionEnabled = false
return cell2
}
```

And above code will add new cell *cell3* in each section at indexPath.row -> 2

Comment: This would be perfect but the problem i am having with this method is that it overwrites what would be indexPath.row ->2 in other sections. i want to add this ROW or SECTION after indexPath.row -> 2. So for example if i have

Comment: food = indexPath.row -> 0

drink = indexPath.row -> 1

apple = indexPath.row -> 2

pine = indexPath.row -> 3

i want to add a new row after indexPath.row -> 2 pushing down apple to the next indexPath
Hope this helps to explain better

@eswar_illuri

Comment: And in all the sections, if indexPath.row > 2, use values in array indexPath.row - 1. For ex. subCat[indexPath.row - 1].subCategoryName

Comment: Yeh i just want it to go between indexPath.row -> 2 and push down everything else. Is there a way to insert a section with switch?